# REST api 403 (Forbidden) error for creating site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, ajax

I'm trying hard to make work this code:

```
shptService.create_board = function (url, title, description, template) {
            //ensure form digest
            shptService.ensureFormDigest(function (fDigest) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: shptService.hostWebUrl+"/_api/web/webinfos/add",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(
                          {
                              'parameters': {
                                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' },
                                  'Url': url,
                                  'Title': title,
                                  'Description': description,
                                  'Language': 1033,
                                  'WebTemplate': 'sts',
                                  'UseUniquePermissions': false
                              }
                          }
                      ),
                        headers: { 
                            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", 
                            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": fDigest
                    },
                    success: doSuccess,
                    error: doError
                });


            });
        };
```

i got from this source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx#bk_CreateSite   but I'm having this error : 
403 (Forbidden) .can anybody tell me why i'm getting this problem or a solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forbidden Error Generally occours because of these two reasons.

1. Your Form Digest value is not correct.
2. The user you are running tests as doesnt have the requisite permissions.

To solve 1 - use `$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()` to get the form digest value. In case you are not getting/able to resolve the value, you may consider refreshing the form digest value by hitting the `/contextinfo` endpoint

```
var getFormDgst= function(url) {

  var req = {};
  req.url = url + "/_api/contextinfo";
  req.method = "POST";
  req.body = "";
  req.header = {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  };
  req.success = function(data) {

    //get context info from data.
    $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue)

  };
  req.failure = function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {

  }
  $ajax(req);      
}
```

The case 2 is easier to solve -  you just give the requisite permission :)

[Source : Wiktor Wilan's Blog](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript)

Comment: it brings me to this new error : 500 (Internal Server Error) :(

Comment: Are you using sharepoint 2013 server or 0365

Comment: I'm using O365  ..im currently developing sharepoint hosted app

Comment: log the error - in req.failure - add a statement, `console.log(data)` Open developer tools in browser, and in console, check the error details that get logged

Comment: "A sub site cannot be created in an app site.\" when is use  url: shptService.appWebUrl+"/_api/web/webinfos/add"   and when i use url: shptService.hostWebUrl+"/_api/web/webinfos/add" "readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden"

Comment: are you using `appsitecontext` to update in host site?

Comment: No .. im not using appsitecontext.

Comment: but GET requites are good i'm only having problem about this POST :(

Comment: Try following the process used to rest in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickpinheiro/archive/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps.aspx. Let my know if you have any issues